# How to show only one row

Tags: sql-server

I have this table structure and the sample data as well. I want to get only one row of the data. But instead it is giving me rows equal to it's child records.

```
--DROP TABLE [Detail];
--DROP TABLE [Master];

--CREATE TABLE [Master]
--(
--ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
--Code VARCHAR(25)
--);

--INSERT INTO [Master] VALUES (1, 'CASH');
--INSERT INTO [Master] VALUES (2, 'CASH');

--CREATE TABLE [Detail]
--(
--ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
--MasterID INT,
--DrAmount Numeric,
--CrAmount Numeric,
--CONSTRAINT FK_MASTER FOREIGN KEY (MasterID)
--REFERENCES [Master](ID)
--);

--INSERT INTO [Detail] VALUES (1, 1, '2200', NULL);
--INSERT INTO [Detail] VALUES (2, 1, NULL, '3200');
--INSERT INTO [Detail] VALUES (3, 1, '1000', NULL);
--INSERT INTO [Detail] VALUES (4, 2, NULL, '3200');
--INSERT INTO [Detail] VALUES (5, 2, '3200', NULL);
```

Here is the query and result:

```
SELECT [MASTER].[Code], [DETAIL].[MasterID], [DETAIL].[CrAmount]
FROM [MASTER], [DETAIL]
WHERE [MASTER].[ID] = [DETAIL].[MasterID]
```

Comment: How about `SELECT TOP 1 ...` ?

Comment: which "one row" would you like to show?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should really switch to 'modern' explicit `join` syntax, rather than the comma separated style. People tend to find it easier to read, and is easier to maintain.

Comment: Well it is doing returning exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) and as @HoneyBadger suggests, it would be better to use the modern explicit join syntax - it is much more clear:

```
select m.code, d.masterid, sum(d.cramount) amount
from [master] m 
     join[detail] d on m.[id] = d.[masterid]
group by m.code, d.masterid
```

Result:

```
code   masterid  amount
CASH    1         3200
CASH    2         3200
```